# QLPreviewView causing a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at runtime when setting previewItem

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift, storyboard, osx-yosemite

PROBLEM: Getting a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18) when setting the previewItem of a QLPreviewView object laid out in a window.

GOAL: Create an app with a preview of file contents and controls below for changing properties of the file being previewed.  The preview must be tied to the size of the window and react to resizing of the window.

SETUP:

Using Xcode 6.1.1 I created a default OS X Cocoa Application using Swift, and Storyboards.

Using Storyboards for layout, there doesn't appear to be a QLPreviewView component in the Object Library, so I used a Custom View object and set the Class to QLPreviewView.  I then set the constraints to allow the preview view to resize with the window frame.

I then linked the Custom View of class QLPreviewView into the ViewController.swift file as a member variable.  In the viewDidLoad() method I added a set the previewItem of the QLPreviewView object to an implementation of the QLPreviewItem protocol.  I also added an import Quartz.

Here is the source for ViewController.swift, as generated by Xcode, then modified by me to add the setup for QLPreviewView.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  PreviewTest
//
//  Created by Derek on 2015-03-02.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Derek. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa
import Quartz

class ViewController: NSViewController {


    @IBOutlet var preview: QLPreviewView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        preview.previewItem = {final class PreviewItem : NSObject, QLPreviewItem {
                var previewItemURL: NSURL! {return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/derek/Pictures/Scan.jpeg")}
                var previewItemTitle: String! {return "Test" }
            }
            return PreviewItem()
        } ()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

The line where preview.previewItem is set gets the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error described at the top when the application is run.

I have successfully created a QLPreviewView and embedded it in a window, however I did it without using the storyboards or constraints, so it's size and position is not managed by the window, which is what I want.

The inline class PreviewItem works fine.  I have tried switching it to a standalone class and then created it to a variable, then set QLPreviewView.previewItem to the variable.  This fails in the same way as the set to previewItem doing it inline.

The inline class PreviewItem also works fine in the non storyboard case and the file scan.jpeg is shown as expected.

Other UI objects, like Text Field work fine when I set them up in a similar way.

I'm hoping to find out what I'm doing wrong here and how to correct it.  Or suggestions on how to approach this goal in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining `PreviewItem` as a nested class instead of the inline definition. JavaScript might define and invoke it with `()` like your program, but I think in Swift the nested class is more general.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    private final class PreviewItem : NSObject, QLPreviewItem {
        var previewItemURL: NSURL! {return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/derek/Pictures/Scan.jpeg")}
        var previewItemTitle: String! {return "Test" }
    }

    @IBOutlet var preview: QLPreviewView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        preview.previewItem = PreviewItem()

        self.view.addSubview(preview)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    ...
}
```

Also make sure the `preview` property is connected to the view by Interface Builder.

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same results.  The EXC_BAD_ACCESS error occurs at previewItem assignment like it does in my example.  I also tried taking the PreviewItem class outside the ViewControler class, making it a top level class.  This also errors on the preview.previewItem = PreviewItem() line.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident the preview property is connected to the view by the Interface Builder, because when it isn't I get a different error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I setup a project and got the same error. Actually without accessing `previewItem` property, I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS when launching the app. In contrast, I didn't get the error if I created an instance of QLPreviewView by code with `init(frame: NSRect)`. It looks QLPreviewView does not support storyboard, but need look deeper.

Comment: Having the same issue in macOS Mojave. QLPreviewView only works when instantiated directly, not from a storyboard